# Regex for removing a html tag <object> in string

Tags: c#, html, regex

I have a html string with simple text:

```
<div><object height="315" width="560"></object><div><object height="315" width="560"></object></div></div>
```

How can I remove any occurence of `<object>` tag and anything inside it? So I want to replace it with empty string which means anything from `<object>` to `</object>` including those tags should be removed?

Comment: One does not use regex to parse non-regular languages.
I will just refer to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: What have you tried so far? The basic pattern should be fairly simple. I didn't use regex in the last few years, but it should be an easy one

Comment: HTML Parsers parse html best: http://html-agility-pack.net

Answer (score 1):

Here you are:

```
var yourString = @"<div><object height=""315"" width=""560""></object><div><object height=""315"" width=""560""></object></div></div>";
yourString = Regex.Replace(yourString, @"<object.+?\/object>", String.Empty);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to parse or modify HTML i recommend a real Html-Parser like `HtmlAgilityPack`:

```
var doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(html);
foreach (var node in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//object"))
    node.Remove();

// if you need it as string:
var writer = new StringWriter();
doc.Save(writer);
html = writer.ToString();
```

The result is (also the nested divs are removed as desired):

```
<div><div></div></div>
```